# the named parameter 'builder' is required but there's no corresponding argument, try adding the requiered argument

Tags: flutter, firebase, arguments

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 - class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget
   build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
           title: 'Flutter Firebase',
           home: Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(title: Text('tareas firebase')),
             body: StreamBuilder(
               stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tareas').snapshots(),
             ),
           ));   } }
```

Comment: it tells you what is wrong. You need to use the builder argument in the streambuilder. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

error telling you itself what is problem, you need to use stream and builder arguments as both are required. Builder property build your widget as per your condition, for more details see below example -

Note- `AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot` you need to define what type os data you are receiving by defining type in AsyncSnapshot<?>.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: // any int type stream here ,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot){
        return Container();
      },
    )
```

For more details - [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)